# YouTube & Android: keep playing video in Activity

Tags: android, layout, video, android-fragments, youtube

I want to achieve the same effect as in the official YouTube app. When the user drag and drops the video, the current watching video will be zoomed in and pinned in left corner and user is still able to scroll the list videos.

I tried moving the fragment from one view to another, but the video become black and cannot do anything.

```
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.remove(youtubeContentFragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
    getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
    fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.small_video_frame, youtubeContentFragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

I also tried another approach by adding the layout contain fragment to `WindowManager`, but the video started lagging a lot.

Does anybody know how to achieve this effectthat? You can see the [YouTube App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.youtube) for a show case of this usage.